# A puzzle with some jumping frogs

Tags: co.combinatorics, puzzle

(The following puzzle is ispired by [this nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3HDnrehyDM) of Gordon Hamilton on Numberphile)

In a pond there are $n$ leaves placed in a circle, for convenience they are numbered clockwise by $0,1,\ldots,n-1$. At the beginning, on each leaf there is a frog, so there are $n$ frogs. At each turn, the frogs can jump accordingly to the following rule: "If on leaf $j$ there are $k \geq 1$ frogs and if on leaf $(j + k) \bmod n$ there is at least one frog, then all the $k$ frogs on leaf $j$ can jump on leaf $(j + k) \bmod n$".

**Is it true that the $n$ frogs can finally be all on the same leaf if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$?**

It is quite easy to prove that if $n$ is a power of $2$ then there is a sequence of jumps that leads all the frogs on the same leaf. On the other hand, I checked by a brute force algorithm that no such sequence exists if $n \leq 14$ is not a power of $2$.

**NOTE:** I previously asked [this question on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170322/a-puzzle-with-some-jumping-frogs) and I got non answers.

**UPDATE 1:** aorq checked that the answer is YES for all $n \leq 50$.

**UPDATE 2:** It might be worth trying to solve first this relaxed version of the problem:

To each solution of the puzzle associate a directed graph on the vertexes $0,1,\ldots,n-1$, where a directed edge $i \to j$ means a jump of all the frogs from leaft $i$ to leaf $j$. Say that the solution has $\ell$ *leader frogs* if its associated directed graph has exactly $\ell$ sources.

**For which $\ell$ is it true that the $n$ frogs can finally be all on the same leaf using a series of jumps with $\ell$ leader frogs, if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$?**

We know that $\ell = 1$ does the job, since with only one leader frog the problem is equivalent to "For which $n$ are the first $n$ triangular numbers distinct modulo $n$" and the answer is "only for $n$ a power of $2$".

Comment: I guess you mean that at each step exactly one leaf-full of frogs jump.  No simultaneous jumps.  Right?

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Yes, no simultaneous jumps.

Comment: @abc Both are solutions when $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: If this is possible for $n$ and possible for $m$ then it is possible for $nm$. First perform each of the $n-1$ jumps that solve the problem for $n$, performing each jump $m$ times, translated by an integer multiple of $n$ each time, and ending in a configuration where $m$ lilies each have $n$ frogs. Then perform the $m-1$ jumps that solve the problem for $m$, each scaled by $n$.

Comment: @WillSawin: what if for $n$ lilies one of the frogs needs to make a full circle around the pond, in order for all of them to meet at the same lily? (I doubt that there is such $n$ for which only solutions with a full circle exist, but nevertheless.)

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev: Will's construction still works.  While I advise you to "just try it", the reasoning is roughly that when a frog "goes around the circle" and thus leaves what appears to be its $n$ consecutive lilies (among $nm$), another frog from the adjacent $n$ lilies shows up exactly where you want it to be.  The $m$ frogs among $nm$ with numbers $i\bmod n$ *together* act like one frog among $n$ with number $i$.

Comment: Naive question, can we prove that $n$ has to be even?

Comment: I think you should explain more precisely what happens when you rule can be activated by several leafs at the same time. Do the frog choose one move to be perform, and try to get all on the same leaf (i.e. the question is whether there exist a sequence of allowed moves that ends up with all frogs at the same leaf), or do you ask when all sequence of allowable moves end up with the frogs on the same leaf? It has some flavor in common with the Abelian sandpile, except we don't seem to have Abelianity here.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner I ask if there exists sequence of allowed moves that ends up with all frogs on the same leaft.

Answer (score 12):

Following David Speyer's improvement, given a rooted tree on $n$ vertices, we number each vertex $v$ with an integer $i_v$ mod $n$ so that the root is numbered $0$ and, if vertex $v_1$ is a child of vertex $v_2$ then $i_{v_1}$ is $i_{v_2}$ plus the number of descendants of $v_1$ (including $v_2$).

We say a rooted tree is valid if all the vertices $v$ have distinct numbers $i_v$. Each solution to the frog-jumping puzzle with $n$ lilies gives a valid rooted tree.

I've just noticed a simplification:

We can express the condition "if vertex $v_1$ is a child of vertex $v_2$ then $i_{v_1}$ is $i_{v_2}$ plus the number of descendants of $v_1$ (including $v_2$)." in a way that does not involve the root. Given two vertices of a tree, connected by an edge, each vertex of the tree is on one side of the edge or the other. The descendants on the child vertex are exactly on that side, so saying $i_{v_1}=i_{v_2}$ plus descendents of $v_1$ is equivalent to saying that $i_{v_1}$ is $i_{v_2}$ plus the number of the $v_1$ side, which is equivalent to saying that $i_{v_2}$ is $i_{v_1}$ plus the number on the $v_2$ side, as the numbers on both sides add up to $n$.

One consequence of this is that the validity of a rooted tree does not depend on the root.

Edit: A variant of this argument in different language was given by Gerhard Paseman in the comments. I didn't read it very carefully and didn't understand his language.

This also allows me to construct $2^{ {m \choose 2}}$ valid rooted trees on $2^m$ vertices, as David Speyer predicted.

The argument proceeds by induction. Given a valid rooted tree $T$ on $2^m$ vertices, fix a vertex $v \in T$ and consider $T \cup T$, with the two copies connected $v$ to $v$, with only the root in the first $T$ preserved. This numbering will have the property that for $w$ in one copy of $T$ and $w'$ its mirror image in the other copy of $T$, $i_{w}= i_{w'} + 2^m$ - using the local description we can see the difference $i_w-i_{w'}$ is independent of $w$, and by setting $w=v$ we see the difference is $2^m$. This immediately implies the $i_w$ are different modulo $2^{m+1}$ - to be equal mod $2^{m+1}$, $i_{w_1}$ and $i_{w_2}$ must first be equal mod $2^m$, which implies because $T$ is valid that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are either equal or mirror images, hence equal.

If there are $2^{{m\choose 2}}$ trees on $2^m$ vertices, and we have $2^m$ choices for which vertex to join them at, this gies a total of $2^{{m\choose 2}+m}= 2^{{m+1 \choose 2}}$ possibilities on $2^{m+1}$ vertices.

It is easy to see that we don't double count here. Any tree has at most one edge with an equal number of vertices on both sides, so every tree arises from this construction in at most one way.

I think it's reasonable to conjecture that these are the only solutions.

---

Here's an equivalent formulation of this conjecture:

> Every valid tree with more than one vertex admits a nontrivial automorphism.

Under this assumption, we can inductively prove that every valid tree has the stated form.

First, note that no valid tree has an automorphism with a fixed vertex. We could take that point to be the root, and then the function $i_v$ would be automorphism-invariant and hence would not be injective.

Second, recall that every automorphism of a tree fixes either a vertex or an edge.

Given a nontrivial automorphism that fixes an edge, its square fixes both vertices on that edge. So its square must be trivial, because the tree has no nontrivail automorphisms with fixed points. Hence it is an involution that exchanges the two sides of the edge.

It remains to check that each side of the edge is individually a valid tree with $n/2$ vertices. But this is easy - for an automorphisms $\sigma$, the function $i_{\sigma(v)}-i_v$ is constant, and equal to $n/2$ for both sides of the fixed edge, hence equal to $n/2$ everywhere. Since distinct vertices have distinct $i-v$ modulo $n$, it follows that distinct vertices have distinct $i_v$ modulo $n/2$ unless they are mirror images, sodistinct vertices on the same side have distinct $i_v$ mod $n/2$ and hence each side s a valid tree on $n/2$ vertices.

This shows it comes from one step of my construction, applied to a valid tree. By induction, it comes from an iteration of my construction, starting with the $1$-vertex tree.

---

One can use this idea, and the fact that the only automorphism-free trees on $\leq 8$ vertices are the one-vertex tree, $E_7$, and $E_8$, to find all valid trees on $\leq 8$ vertices without a brute force  search.

However, I don't see any possible way to prove a valid tree has an automorphism.

---

My previous post:

Here is a reformulation of the problem that might be interesting:

We can view a solution to the puzzle as a binary tree. Start with $n$ leaves for each of the $n$ frogs, unordered. At each point in time, each node of the tree without a parent will represent a lily with frogs on it. Whenever the frogs from one lily jump unto another lily, add a new node that is a parent of both, with the first lily on the left and the second lily on the right. Finally we end up with a single node, the root.

We can reconstruct the position of each frog by working backwards, from the top of the tree to the bottom. Set the root node to have position $0$, and then set the right child of any node to have the same position as its parent and the left child to have the same position as its parent, minus the number of leaves among its descendants. If all the leaves have distinct positions mod $n$, it is a valid tree, otherwise, it isn't.

So a very rough heuristic, assuming that a random binary tree has a $n!/n^n$ probability of having all distinct positions among its leaves, suggest that the number of valid solutions (which is smaller than the $f(n)$ calculated by abc, because we consider solutions up to equivalence) should be $C_{n-1} n!/n^n \approx ( 4/e)^n$, which goes to $\infty$ with $n$, but is however not so big for $n \leq 14$ (at most $6$). So perhaps a little more numerical data would be helpful?

However this heuristic is probably quite bad. To me it seems like different leaves can have the same position mod $n$ for at least two separate reason - local reasons, which force two nodes to have the exact same position, and global reasons where they are distinct but equal mod $n$. Probably these should be treated differently.

Comment: Hi Will! I was thinking along the same lines, but many of these binary trees describe the same solution: Suppose we have frogs on pads A, B and C (among others) and the next two jumps are C--->A, B--->A. If we switch the other to B--->A, C--->A, then your encoding gives different trees, but either both are solutions or neither. I think it is better to make a tree with n vertices, where there is an edge i--->j if there is a jump from i to j. This leads to the asymptotic (2/e)^n, which suggests finitely many solutions.

Comment: I extended the OP's search up to n=21 with no solutions except powers of 2. Here is something striking: For $0 \leq m \leq 4$, the number of distinct trees I got from the construction in my previous comment is $2^{\binom{m}{2}}$.

Comment: For what it is worth, I got that the number of solutions which don't have "local conflicts", as you call them, is 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 21, 40, 76, 160, 331, 716, 1502, 3170, 6912, 14883, 32192, 71443, 156712 for $n \leq 20$. This appear to roughly double each time.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yeah, that modification definitely makes sense. Now that the asymptotic goes to $0$ so rapidly with $n$, it makes me not very hopeful that there is a nice explanation of why there is no solution for $n$ not a power of $2$. It could be true "by chance".

Comment: Any idea where the $2^{\binom{m}{2}}$ comes from?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Can you explain what precisely you were counting that was $2^{ {m \choose 2}}$? I didn't quite follow.

Comment: The number of solutions with $2^m$ frogs, if we count two solutions as the same if they give the same $2^m$-vertex tree. For example, the two solutions for $4$ frogs are 2 ---> 1 ---> 3 ---> 0 and 3 ---> 2 ---> 0 <--- 1. Again, I draw an edge i ---> j if there is a hop from pad i to pad j.

Comment: Here are the solutions for 8 frogs. I encode a tree as a list, the first element of which is the position of the root and the following elements are its children. {0, {7, {5, {2, {6, {1, {3, {4}}}}}}}} ; {0, {7, {5, {1, {3, {4}}, 
{2}}, {6}}}} ; {0, {7, {3, {5, {6}}, {4}}, {1, {2}}}} ; {0, {6, {3, {7, 
{2, {4, {5}}}}}}, {1}} ; {0, {6, {2, {4, {5}}, {3}}, {7}}, {1}} ; {0, 
{5, {1, {4, {6, {7}}}}}, {2, {3}}} ; {0, {4, {7, {1, {2}}}}, {3, {5, 
{6}}}} ; {0, {4, {6, {7}}, {5}}, {2, {3}}, {1}}.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yeah, that phenomenon is really interesting. I think I need to  draw the diagrams and play around with them to try to figure it out.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer For $1 \leq m \leq 3$, each solution with $2^m$ frogs contains a unique vertex with exactly $2^{m-1}$ descendants (including itself). The subtree of descendants of this vertex, and the tree with that subtree excised, both are solutions for $2^{m-1}$ frogs. Moreover, each solution with $2^{m-1}$ frogs appears $2^{m-1}$ times this way, with each residue class mod $2^{m-1}$ appearing once as the residue class of the special vertex. Of course if this were true for all $m$ it would explain your count.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer That seems out of reach, but maybe one can show that trees satisfying this description exist, giving a lower bound of $2^{ {m \choose 2}}$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Can you comment a little more on the $2^n$ part of your asymptotic?  It seems to agree with the number of solutions without local conflicts, but I haven't been able to reproduce the heuristic reasoning.

Comment: @aorq I was thinking about this last night, and I couldn't either. I'll see if I can do better tonight...

Comment: You might consider the dual game, which aorq seems to do with his (gender presumption) code: start with N frogs on one pad and allowable moves are K frogs from a pad with J greater than K frogs onto an empty pad K spaces in the preferred direction.  I used a similar approach with some success in my prime leapfrog game discussed on MathOverflow.  It allows you to reorganize attempts into common configurations more smoothly.  Gerhard "Some Steps Backward, More Forward" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yup, this is what my code does. I dynamically list all positions which are reachable starting with N frogs on leftmost lilly pad, thinking of the pads as an infinite line, and taking N-1 jumps to end up on different pads. This gets up to 16 quickly, and to the low 20's with some grinding, but then stalls out. (continued)

Comment: I have other ideas for improvement, but not now.

Comment: While your tree approach offers a similar perspective, my suggestion does not presume a final state of n leaves, but just considers the achievable positions under rotational symmetry. One interesting aspect similar to your observation is that if K frogs jump from the initial node after other jumps are are, this is equivalent to moving the initial node K steps forward, and making the first jump with N-K frogs. Gerhard "From Trees To The Pond" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: Ah OK.  If I think of possible improvements I will mention them here.  Gerhard "Hoping To Leap To Conclusion" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: Here is one. Consider a play in the dual game as a multi branched tree. I think you can show each branch as disjoint, meaning they affect different non intersecting parts of the pond. Now the observation above means you can reshape the tree by bending one branch down and making its node the root. Now you iterate, reshaping the tree into a chain. So every game state should be reachable by a (hopefully simpler) branching succession of moves.  Gerhard "How Is That For Improvement?" Paseman, 2017.03.29.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer It seems that the number of unlabeled trees on $n$ vertices is actually exponential in $n$, with the base of the exponential $2.95576528565\dots$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Unlabeled_trees

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! Here it would be more natural to look at rooted trees where no two siblings (vertices with same parent) have the same number of descendants. I suspect that changes the base, but I have no reason to think it is 2. I think I was just wrong.

Comment: Here is another heuristic. Consider all $n^{n-2}$ labeled trees on the $n$ Lily pads. Root each tree at pad $0$ and, starting from the leaves working in, try to jump toward the root. The probability that a given jump will be legal is (heuristically) $1/n$. So probability that all $n-1$ jumps in a given tree are legal is $n^{n-2}/n^{n-1} = 1/n$. This suggests infinitely many sporadic solutions (since $\sum 1/n$ diverges) but not many. I don't know if I believe this argument or not.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Well, we can already construct more than $\log n$ solutions of size $\leq n$ just by using power of $2$ - indeed it's not hard to find $2^{m/2}$ solutions for $n=2^m$. So that heuristic can't be right on the nose.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I was thinking of a similar heuristic (though I didn't mention it) at the time I wrote my comment.  It seemed to fit my findings better regarding $n-1$ frogs. Re WillSawin: Presumably this heuristic applies "unless there's another reason for solutions", as for powers of two.  But it's all guesswork anyway ...

Comment: Right, I meant the undefined term "sporadic" to mean "outside the ones that exist for good reasons". I'd be interested in seeing the details of that $2^{m/2}$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer An upper bound for the number of trees with the property you desire is the number of trees without extra automorphisms, and an upper bound for this is the number of trees counting by the inverse of the automorphism group, which is $n^{n-1}/n! \approx e^n$. So that heuristically matches your calculation. However, if you disallow some subtree (such as a particular special case of a tree where two siblings have the same number of descendants) the exponential constant will go down somewhat.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer It just comes from composing the two trees on $m=2$ using the process I suggested in my commented on the main question.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I now have a construction that gets the full $2^{m \choose 2}$.

Comment: I really like your simplification.  Honestly, it seems like only a few steps away from a proof ... but I haven't been able to figure it out.  My early intuition for this problem really suggested using that "the first $n$ triangular numbers are distinct modulo $n$ iff $n$ is a power of $2$", perhaps by incremental modifications of one of these tree descriptions ... but I haven't been able to get that to work either.

Comment: Two comments: (1) Based on your construction, a good first step to a proof would be to show that any admissible tree has an edge that splits it in half. A special case of that is that there are no solutions with $n$ odd. (2) I still don't know whether or not I expect these to be the only solutions. Our heuristics are almost perfectly on the boundary of predicting sporadic solutions or not doing so.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I have a couple reasons to make this conjecture: (1) Numerical evidence. (2) If you take out the root from your calculations, one predicts only finitely many sporadic solutions. (3) By a variant of this construction, any one solution will actually give many more. (4) It's fun to make a bold conjecture. I certainly wouldn't stake my life on it.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Well I know the following fact: Every graph either has an edge that splits it in half or a single vertex such that every branch of the tree coming out of that vertex has less than half the vertices. So it would be good to eliminate that case. The obvious thing to try is to set that vertex to be the root and go back to thinking about frogs. But I can't see how to make that condition have any meaning on the level of frogs.

Comment: @aorq Yeah, what really concerns me is that it seems like, if there is a proof, one can't prove it as a corollary of that fact about triangular numbers - one will somehow have to generalize that fact.  But that to me seems like a number theory fact, and I don't know how to bring number theory into this.

Comment: @aorq Here is an experiment I want to do, but maybe you can do it faster. Let $p$ be an odd prime and $n$ a multiple of $p$. Are there trees with $n$ vertices where each label modulo $p$ is used $n/p$ times?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Here's one with $n=15$, $p=3$ in what I think is a correct adaptation of your notation: {0,{1,{2},{2},{2}}},{0,{1},{1}},{0,1,1},{0,{2}},{0,{2}}}

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I added a new argument showing that my claimed conjecture is equivalent to the conjecture that every valid tree with more than one vertex has a nontrivial automorphism, a conjecture that aorq's numerical experiments now imply holds for $n\leq 50$. Unfortunately I have no clue why that should be true.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: My program has now found that there are $2^{\binom{m}{2}}$ solutions for $n=2^m$ for $m\le 6$, thus adding one more data point to that conjecture.  (It has also verified the main conjecture up to $n\le 64$.)

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: In an earlier comment, you say "Now you iterate, reshaping the tree into a chain." Do you mean this literally, that every tree can be reshaped into a path? If so, then that's a proof! If not, what do you mean? Is there a reshaping operation that sometimes simplifies the tree?

Comment: Yes, I did say that, unfortunately it is not true. The reason is that I can only manipulate the root and an immediate child this way, because their descendants sum to n. On a subtree whose descendant sum to less than n, I cannot justify such a reshape.  I apologize for the misstatement. Originally I thought I could, then tried to edit it out, but forgot to remove the chain part.  However, there may be a similar game tree equivalence that allows a reshaping, such as regrafting a branch.  Gerhard "Not Adept At Mathematical Bonsai" Paseman, 2017.04.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yeah, I believe your move is equivalent to changing the root, which I discuss in the my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I have verified the result by computer for $n\le 60$.  I have included simplified, working C++11 code below; you may need to add a `-std=c++11` flag to compile.  (My actual code has been changing frequently as I attempt different optimizations.)  Beware: as with all code, it may be incorrect.

The strategy is to find possible configurations in the backwards/"dual game" as discussed by [Will Sawin](https://mathoverflow.net/users/18060/will-sawin), [David Speyer](https://mathoverflow.net/users/297/david-speyer), and [Gerhard Paseman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3402/gerhard-paseman) below [another answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/265802/1079).  The output prints the number of configurations found for each `K`.  For a given $N$, the smaller entries will agree with [David's calculations regarding "local conflicts"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265513/a-puzzle-with-some-jumping-frogs/265802?noredirect=1#comment655963_265802), but the larger ones diverge for two reasons: (1) global conflicts modulo $N$, and (2) distinct trees with identical leaves (ie "multiplicity" as discussed in the comments below this answer).  The set `possible[K]` contains all possible configurations that can be collapsed from `K` frogs back to a single, fixed leaf.  The configurations are encoded and manipulated using bit operations.

One lesson learned from the output is that it is *usually* (but not always) possible for $n-1$ of the $n$ frogs to end up on one leaf.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

const int N = 32;
static_assert( N <= 64, "The optimizations herein use 64-bit integers." );

std::set<uint64_t> possible[N+1];

int main( ) {
    std::cout << "N=" << N << std::endl;
    possible[1].insert( {1UL} );
    for( int K = 2; K <= N; K++ ) { 
        for( int I = 1; I < K; I++ ) {
            for( uint64_t p : possible[I] ) {
                uint64_t from = ((p & ((1UL << (N-I)) - 1UL)) << I) | (p >> (N-I));
                for( uint64_t to : possible[K-I] ) {
                    if( (to & from) == 0 )
                        possible[K].insert( to | from );
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << K << "\t" << possible[K].size() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << (possible[N].size() > 0 ? "Success!" : "Failure.") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My calculations suggest that the exceptions to $n-1$ frogs being able to jump onto one leaf for $n\le 50$ are $n=6, 10, 18, 22, 26, 34, 42, 44$.

Comment: My new code has confirmed the conjecture for $n\le 50$ (again).  With some extra optimizations, this time $n=50$ only took an hour.

Comment: Can you count the number of solutions for $n=32$? In particular, is it 1024?

Comment: David Speyer's heuristic suggests that the number of solutions with $n-1$ frogs is $n-1$ (the number of choices for the missing frog, if we assume we end with all frogs on lily zero) times $n-1^{n-3}$ (the number of trees on the remaining $n-1$ lilies) divided by $n^{n-2}$ (multiplying by the ``probability" that all jumps are legal), which is $(n-1/n)^{n-2} \approx 1/e$. So it fits the heuristic reasonably well that there usually is a solution.

Comment: @WillSawin: re your first comment, not as written.  The code doesn't count multiplicity at all.  However, I will look into modifying it so that I can reproduce the counts for $n=2^m$ as David has done.  Re your second comment, the new heuristic does seem to fit reasonably well.  This program also gives the empirical finding that the number of solutions with $n-k$ frogs is "independent" of $n$ and fairly predictable for fixed, small $k$. (Edit to add: the "solutions" counted in the second point are "configurations", not trees --- in the sense that there's only one configuration with $n$ frogs.)

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes, there are 1024.  In more words: I can confirm that there are $2^{\binom{m}{2}}$ trees in David Speyer's sense for $n=2^m$ for $m\le 5$.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but there is an algebraic reformulation of the problem which is equivalent when $n$ is a prime.

First, we assume that at the end of the process all the frogs wish to end up on leaf $0$. For each $1 \le k \le n$, we define $a_k$ to be the number of frogs that eventually land on leaf $k$ (so the frogs on leaf $k$ all jump to leaf $k+a_k \pmod{n}$). Also, set $a_0 = n$.

Since every frog that reaches leaf $k$ comes from some leaf $j$ with $j + a_j \equiv k \pmod{n}$, we get

$a_k = 1 + \sum_{j \ne 0,\ j + a_j \equiv k \pmod{n}} a_j.$

Multiplying the $k$th equation above by $f(k)$ where $f : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is any function, and summing over all possible $k$, we get

$\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} f(k)a_k \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} f(k) + \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} a_kf(k+a_k) \pmod{n}.$

If $f(0) \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, we can simplify slightly by replacing all the sums by sums from $1$ to $n-1$ (since $a_0 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$). Now the idea is to use the fact that if $n = p$ is prime, then functions $f : \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$ are the same as polynomials having no constant coefficient.

**Theorem:** If $n = p$ is prime, then the frogs can all end up on the same leaf if and only if there are $a_1, ..., a_{p-1} \in \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ such that for each $1 \le d \le 2(p-1)$ we have

$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} a_k((a_k+k)^d - k^d) = \begin{cases}0 & p-1 \nmid d\\ 1 & p-1 \mid d\end{cases}.$

**Proof:** Let $a_0 = 0$. For each $k \in \mathbb{F}_p$, let $f_k$ be a polynomial of degree at most $2p-2$ having roots at each element of $(\{0, 1, ..., p-1\} \cup \{a_1+1, ..., a_{p-1}+p-1\})\setminus\{k\}$, and such that $f_k(k) = 1$. Writing $f_k(x) = \sum_{d=0}^{2p-2} c_d x^d$ and summing the given equalities with weights $c_d$ for $d \ge 1$ (together with a trivial equality with weight $c_0$), we get

$\sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} f_k(k)a_k = \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} f_k(k) + \sum_{k = 0}^{p-1} a_kf_k(k+a_k),$

and by the choice of $f_k$ this is equivalent to

$a_k = 1 + \sum_{j + a_j = k} a_j.$

Make a directed graph on $\{0, ..., p-1\}$ with $j\rightarrow k$ whenever $j+a_j = k$. Note that every vertex $k$ has outdegree $1$ if $a_k \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $0$ otherwise, that a vertex $k$ has a self-loop if and only if $a_k = 0$, and that every vertex $k$ with indegree $0$ has $a_k = 1$. More generally, for every vertex $k$ which is not part of a cycle, $a_k$ is congruent modulo $p$ to the number of vertices $j$ such that there is a directed path starting at $j$ and ending at $k$ (including $k$).

Since vertex $0$ has $a_0 = 0$ and therefore has a self-loop, the collection of vertices $j$ such that there is a directed path from $j$ to $0$ forms a rooted tree, directed towards $0$, and the number of vertices in this tree is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$. Since there are only $p$ vertices total in the whole digraph, every vertex belongs to this tree.

Thus the whole digraph corresponds to a rooted tree with root $0$, and it describes a strategy for the frogs to all jump to $0$.

---

Given the above result, it seems tempting to try to use Gröbner basis methods to attack the problem for small primes $p$. For $p = 3$ and using $d = 1,2,3$ we have, after renaming $a = a_1, b = a_2$, the system of equations

$a^2 + b^2 = 0, a^3 + b^3 + 2a^2 + 4b^2 = 1, a^4 + b^4 = 0.$

The first and third of these imply that $a^4 = b^4 = a^2b^2 = 0,$ so after raising both sides of the second equation to the second power we get $0 = 1$, a contradiction.

For $p = 5$, computations with Macaulay 2 show that the equations corresponding to $d = 1, 2, ..., 5$ give a contradiction. For $p = 7,$ after several hours Macaulay 2 claims that the equations corresponding to $d = 1, 2, ..., 7$ give a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** As pertains to **UPDATE 2**, the post below gives references to settle the case of $\ell = 1$.

---

This is a bit long for a comment, but I thought it worthwhile in case the following is non-obvious:

> It is quite easy to prove that if $n$ is a power of $2$ then there is a sequence of jumps that leads [to] all the frogs on the same leaf.

(Maybe this really is "quite easy to prove," but I would not have known this to be the case at a glance without a familiarity with the references included below...)

If you begin with a frog and have it jump $1$ leaf, then have the newly formed duo jump $2$ leaves, then have the newly formed trio jump $3$ leaves, etc, then you move around the leaves by $+1, +2, +3, \ldots$ and, since you are jumping in a circle of $n$ leaves, the positions of frogs jumping together are at the triangular numbers modulo $n$.

And so the assertion elsewhere in this thread, which (in particular) covers the quotation-pull above, is that this will be sufficient to reach all the leaves if $n$ is a power of $2$. Equivalently, the set of the first $n$ triangular numbers modulo $n$ is $\{0, 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ if $n$ can be written as a power of $2$.

In fact, the last statement is true with **if** replaced by **iff**, and this was the subject of a very nice write-up in the New York Times' *Numberplay* column as [**Daniel Finkel’s Circle-Toss Game**](https://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/11/03/toss/). There is another proof of this proposition by induction [**here**](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/triangular-numbers-mod-2n/), which includes a pointer to an earlier proof by D Knuth in:

> The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 3, Chapter 6.4. Excercise 20 in the second edition.

Of course, with respect to the main question:

> Is it true that the $n$ frogs can finally be all on the same leaf if and only if $n$ is a power of $2$?

just the "if" is covered: the strategy above (as proved in the three different references given) shows how to get all the frogs to the same leaf for $n$ being a power of $2$. The "only if" part is what remains difficult, since the OP is proposed in greater generality than the circle-toss game: instead of the frogs needing to jump together in the triangular number pattern already described, one has access to lots of other patterns. I have no new suggestions for the "only if" component, although perhaps seeing the different proofs mentioned above (I especially enjoy the "multi-ball argument" in the first link) could serve as some sort of inspiration.

Comment: Fwiw, I think the "quite easy to prove" strategy is the one where every other frog jumps, so they end up on every second leaf.  And then you repeat, so they end up on every fourth leaf, every eighth leaf, etc., until they all end up on one leaf.

Comment: Another reason this might be useful - You can view the argument in my answer that constructs $2^{ {m \choose 2}}$ solutions on $2^m$ vertices as a generalization of the proof in your second link.